# WPF TextBox change color on focus

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I try to change color on my input box when is focused.

First I declare input button:

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="usernameTextBox"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Height="23" 
         Margin="115,31,0,0"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="277"
         GotFocus="usernameTextBox_GotFocus"/>
```

And below I try to add style for that textbox

```xml
<Style x:Key="usernameTextBox"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsFocused"
                   Value="true">
               <Setter Property="Background"
                       Value="{StaticResource OnMouseOverColor}" />
         </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Error:

> Error 1   A value of type 'Style' cannot be added to a collection or
>   dictionary of type
>   'UIElementCollection'.    D:\VS\VIM\VIM_WPF\login.xaml    15  9   VIM_Wpf

Any other solution how to fix this?

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either you define your style as a resource (e.g. in your usercontrol / window's resources), and then do something like

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource theKeyOfYourStyle}" ..../>
```

or you explicitly set it in the TextBox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="usernameTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="115,31,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="277" GotFocus="usernameTextBox_GotFocus">
  <TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
       <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OnMouseOverColor}" />
         </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
   </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: {"Cannot find resource named 'OnMouseOverColor'. Resource names are case sensitive."}

Comment: `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />`
this work

Comment: OnMouseOverColor: I was taking this from your code sample. Of course this assumes you actually have a resource with the key "OnMouseOverColor" defined anywhere within the accessible resources to that textbox - the error message suggests that you don't. So make sure you have that resource defined in the textbox or one of its parent elements, and its key is OnMouseOverColor. If you don't want to use a resource for your background, setting the color directly (e.g. as your "Yellow") works of course.